# Hibernate Criteria join two tables

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria

I've 3 table:
PERSON: ID, NAME, SURNAME
TEAM: ID, NAME, PERSON, ROLE
ROLE: ID, POSITION
where TEAM could have a list of PERSON

I need to create a query, with Hibernate Criteria, like this:
select * from PERSON p, TEAM t
    where t.ROLE = "myRole" and t.PERSON = p.id

I want to get the list of PERSON in TEAM with a given ROLE.
Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team has a list of person. Therefore instead of having Person column in Team table, you should have team_id column in Person table. And I assume Role is associated with Person.Thus your tables should be like the following:

Person: ID, NAME, SURNAME, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID
Team: ID, NAME
Role:ID, POSITION

Then the query for getting list of Person in a given Team with a given role is:

`Select * from Person p, Team t, Role r where p.team_id=t.id and p.role_id=r.id and r.position = givenPosition and t.name=givenTeam`

In Criteria

```
`Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class, "p");
c.createAlias("p.team", "t");
c.createAlias("p.role", "r");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("t.name", givenTeam));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("r.position", givenPosition ));`
```

Comment: What if I have to return a VO which will have one column from each table?

Comment: Where are r and t mapped like you mapped p with Person?